# React - Insert an image between the 2nd and 3rd <p> tag

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component

```
<Text>
   <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: apiContent}} />
</Text>
```

that displays HTML coming from an API that may look like the following:

```
<div>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>more text</p>
  <p>more text</p>
  <p>more text</p>
  <p>still more text</p>
</div>
```

How do I insert an image, which is another React component, between the 2nd and 3rd p tag?

I know how to do it in vanilla JS, but have trouble doing it the React way.

Comment: How do you render this HTML coming from an API?

Comment: And the image you want to insert, is it just some HTML or is it a React component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be curious to see the other answers, but I feel like inserting a React component inside some raw HTML is pretty much impossible. The options I can think of are:

- use some library to turn the raw HTML into a tree of React components, and hopefully this library will also include a way to inject custom components in specific places (I don't know any such library, but there probably is one)
- edit the raw HTML to insert an empty container with a unique id at the place you need it (for instance by parsing the HTML into a DocumentFragment, using vanilla JS to insert a div, turning it back into a string, and setting it as innerHTML as you already do), and then use a React portal to inject a React component into that container. Pretty messy...

Answer (score -1):

If it is a react component then it is not **html** so not logical to put it inside **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** tag.
you need to rewrite this react component to an HTML string  and work with the html that is coming from API as a string.
that means you can split the incoming string of html on the second **closing p tag**
and add the new html string in the middle.